# Find specific functional genes from a list?

Tags: sequence-annotation, functional-annotation

I have compiled a list of genes that are distinct from 2 different conditions. 
From this list (of about 600 human genes), I want to find out if any of the genes in this list have acetyl transferase function i.e. are acetylases.

Is there an online platform where I could say put in this list of genes and the output I can select genes which have this property/function?

I.e some sort of gene annotation for functions for a list of human genes?

Comment: Have you looked into any services yet?  Did they not met your needs?

Answer (score 2):

[BioMart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvGT2G0-hYA). Filter by your list of genes and a [GO term](http://amigo.geneontology.org/amigo/search/ontology?q=acetyl%20transferase) linked to acetyl transferase activity.